# Recent files not showing up in list...How to fix this?

Tags: interface

I have looked at my User Pref settings, and have checked the recent file (I have it set at 25)...not sure what is the issue. I have reloaded Blender, used various new versions...tried placing the file on my desk top (versus my wifi B/U network drive)...et me know what other info I can provide and thanks!

Comment: The recent files list is a text file that gets stored in the same place as the startup.blend and userpref.blend In windows it would be C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\version_number\config.  Make sure that the path is accessible to write and that your permissions are set correctly.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78121/can-i-change-default-folder-to-save-startup-file-startup-blend-and-userpref-ble

Comment: To find the location of the recent-files.text file on other OS read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23341/1853

Comment: Also the recent files list is written to by the most recently closed Blender session window. If you open a bunch of files in different windows but close last the first window you opened that session will store no info of all other opened files and on close will only write one recently opened file.

Comment: Also make sure that Blender is opened from that same OS user which was used for previous opening and closing.

Comment: Thanks!  Found the file fixed the folder issue (read-only)!  Great info provided

Comment: My Blender folder in AppData is read Only as well... problem is that AppData itself is Read Only... as well as the entire Users folder. Solution?