# Start blender in video editing mode & script setup

Tags: scripting, video-sequence-editor, video

I am using powershell to install blender on an EC2 instance.  I would like it to default to video editing and configure the properties for the project via automation (powershell if possible).  I would like to set video output to 720p, fps to 30, etc.

Is there a way to automate the configuration?

Comment: I would simply prepare a startup.blend set as you want and replace the default one after installation/deploy

Comment: I have noticed that the path ...\Blender\2.79\config does not exist unless you have saved a user preference file.   This requires me to find the version of blender and create the directory with that specific version.  Is this the only way to get it to load this startup file for a first run of blender?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78121/can-i-change-default-folder-to-save-startup-file-startup-blend-and-userpref-ble