# How do I set a separate user preferences for Blender Portable?

Tags: customization

I want to have separate settings for my copy of Blender Portable on my D: drive than the official version installed in my C: drive

What do I have to change in the portable version to prevent settings from being shared?

EG: If I change the theme in the portable version, the main version also adopts that theme.

The answer provided at:
[Can I change default folder to save startup file (startup.blend and userpref.blend)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78121/can-i-change-default-folder-to-save-startup-file-startup-blend-and-userpref-ble)

Is different than mine due to the portable version overwrites the standard installed version configurations and not in its own folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change default folder to save startup file (startup.blend and userpref.blend)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78121/can-i-change-default-folder-to-save-startup-file-startup-blend-and-userpref-ble)

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos I tried it and it didn't work. Blender portable does not have a 2.8 folder so I created it in the directory Blenderportable.exe is in then added the Config folder then I changed the theme did a ctrl+U both versions changed and nothing was written in the new folder.

Comment: what you mean by "blender portable"? are you using a simple "archive" version downloaded from blender.org? if yes, the duplicate linked solution should work (although 2.8 is not yet released and could not behave as 2,7x does)

Comment: @m.ardito https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/blender_portable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could try to alter the BLENDER_USER_CONFIG (Directory for user configuration files) environment variable when using portable or installed version,

as specified [in manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html)

like starting blender with a little script that sets/resets the env vars to what you need...

Both the manual (link above) and also "blender --help" output state that you can use those env vars.

The only other method I know of is what was suggested by @DuarteFarrajotaRamos with the linked other question, much simpler, no scripting required, and allows also multiple different blender instance to run *toghether* each with different config/preferences, if needed: this is also explained in manual [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html?highlight=environment%20variables#configuring-directories).

If this is not working it could be due to some different behavior of those "portable apps" you're using, maybe. You coul try to use an official archive, extract and run it. I tried and by just copying the "config" folder into the 2.79 folder gave me a separate configuration/preference set.

Comment: As I don't know how to script I cannot confirm if this answer is correct.

Comment: that depends on your operating system... see https://www.schrodinger.com/kb/1842 ie, you need to learn how to script for your OS, and set BLENDER_USER_CONFIG to some specific folder, then start blender (it should use BLENDER_USER_CONFIG as manual says). On this bse site questions about your OS scripting are offtopic, I guess, but you could ask on http://stackoverflow.com/ maybe.

Comment: @EricHuelin I restored and edited my answer