# Backup Blender addons and settings

Tags: blend-files

I'm moving my current workstation files to a brand new machine. Is there an addon or feature within blender to pack all settings and many addons downloaded/purchased/enables into a single folder?

Best,

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120944/how-can-you-sync-blender-configs-between-multiple-machines

Comment: Thank you. I should clarify that I meant how to sync community/third party add-ons

Comment: that is why I always use a [Portable Version](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63648/what-is-the-proper-way-to-update-a-portable-blender-installation-while-keeping-u/63666#63666)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is already in a single folder. You could just install Blender and copy that old preferences folder. On Windows it's

```
C:\Users\[YOUR USER NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\[VERSION NUMBER]\
```

This may exclude some more complex add-ons that come in few parts like some render engines.

Comment: Shortcut to the Blender path: "%APPDATA%\Blender Foundation\Blender"

Answer (score 1):

Blender Sync
Save your settings once. Use them anywhere. Carry your Blender configuration with you, use our add-on to sync your keymaps and preferences.Blender Sync is free for everyone! No subscription required. This add-on requires Blender 2.78 or newer.
Available through the Blender Cloud add-on

https://cloud.blender.org/services