# Information about updating from v. 2.79 to v. 2.79b

Tags: installation

One can always be wiser.
Unfortunately, it was not possible to move the settings from v. 2.79 to v. 2.79b. As the included installer installed v. 2.79b on v. 2.79.
Fine. But all my presets disappeared so I have to get started on the gene.
It might not be an idea, in future programs, to provide a "normal" update option.
Or is there a good reason why it should be so?

Comment: You don't say what operating system you are using... but customized settings and preferences are stored in a folder that is not part of the blender program's folder, so they should be available.

Comment: I am using Windows 10.
Where is the folder that is not part of Blender's folder? I'd like to look for something written there

Comment: Read [Where is the startup file stored?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23341/1853) and [Can I change default folder to save startup file (startup.blend and userpref.blend)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78121/can-i-change-default-folder-to-save-startup-file-startup-blend-and-userpref-ble)

Answer (score 1):

Try path: `%APPDATA%/Blender Foundation/Blender/` (Windows) there should be a folder called `2.79`, this is shared between all *2.79 series* of blender include *2.79b*

This is the preference and start up and some script setting folder. You should manually backup these files before update to 2.79b if you are worry about it.

After install 2.79b, you can manually copy back your backup files(not recommend, only setting is lost or blender failed to import old preference)