# How to create ONE addons folder and have any blender version access it?

Tags: add-on

link to, not copy blender 3.6 addons path to Blender 4.0.1
Usually after installing a new Blender, it asks to transfer settings from the previous version. (did not happen this time) It then duplicates all the addons to a new version folder and want to avoid duplicating GB of addon data.

**How to create ONE addons folder and have any blender version access it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either [change the startup folder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78121/can-i-change-default-folder-to-save-startup-file-startup-blend-and-userpref-ble) and make both versions use the same, which has its own share of disadvantages (like possible incompatible startup files or templates), or use multiple script folders.

Go to *Edit > Preferences > File Paths > Scripts Directory* and add as many as you like.

[image]

Comment: that indeed added access to the 3.6 addons path, however, none of the addons will activate. Also how to access the Transfer 3.6 setting to 4.0? After the first launch if you don't, the option is no longer available on the Splash Screen. ~ thanks

Comment: Are they compatible?

Comment: Some of the python APIs have changed between 3.6 and 4.0 so the addons have to be been changed to match. This means that even the internal addons from 3.6 will not install in 4.0, hence the reason for the different version folders.

Comment: ~ Thank you for the explanation