# How can I change the path where add-ons are stored?

Tags: add-on

I installed a blender add-on (BlenderBIM) and I want to save it in a specific directory (not the typical `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\`).

I already tried the steps from this page https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/editors/preferences/addons.html by creating a directory and sub-directory called `addons` and then setting the file path accordingly in my *Preferences > File Paths*.

No matter how often I change and save the preferences or restart blender, the file path of my add-on is still the `AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation` one.

I'm currently using blender 3.6 but I had the same problem with blender 4.0 before.
Is there another way or a trick to change the file path?

Comment: As far as I know, settings under *Preferences > File Paths* are for adding additional script folders, not override the default one. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78121/can-i-change-default-folder-to-save-startup-file-startup-blend-and-userpref-ble/78128#78128

Comment: You could look into  [Junction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction) to mount one folder to another. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos it seems to work, thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome. If an answer is helpful in any way please [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Indeed it is a canned response. Ill remove that part since it doesn't apply here