# Can I move Blender between drives without breaking the installation?

Tags: installation

I'm very new to Blender, and am not aware of it's intricacies. I need to move Blender from F:\ to E:\ . Can I just move the Blender folder to the other drive? Will it break Blender or any add-ons?

Thanks!!

Comment: If you got the Zip version of blender, you can move it and store it wherever you want.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63648

Comment: It shouldn't break *Blender itself* even using installation version. But if you change/delete/move the preference folder located in `users/user/AppData/Roaming/Blender blablabla....`. The preference setting will be lost and Blender will create a new one for you. This could lead to losing add-on setting if you don't take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

The installation folder of Blender can be moved anywhere on your computer at any time.

The only folder that must be taken care of is the [user folder](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html#windows).
That's where are stocked your personal data like preferences and addons. You need to copy that folder if you want to copy your Blender on another computer or have a USB installation that cna be run anywhere.