# Local Config and Userprefs on Network Deployment - How to share an install but allow users to save their own settings per-workstation?

Tags: network

I work in an office setting that handles software installs via push deployments, rather than local installs, for version control and parity purposes.

While attempting a push of Blender 2.93 (with some add-on customization), I'm running into the problem of users not being able to modify their config and userpref files; this means that they cannot enable or disable add-ons at will, cannot create customized startup settings, and Recent Projects does not retain project history. This deployment of Blender also does not appear to retain any customized settings to re-route the add-ons folder to a network drive - when the Scripts directory is manually set in the System menu, it still appears to be reading all plug-ins from the push install directory on C, which cannot be modified. When the user tries to install an add-on from a zip, regardless of local or network location, the add-on *appears* to install but then is not available when searched in the Add-ons menu.

This is understandably frustrating for the users, and I'm sure it's purely an execution issue on my end, but I'm not an IT expert and I'm not sure how to get this working for the team. Is the only answer to locally install and customize Blender on each individual workstation? Is there some kind of read/write priority on the deployed userpref and config files that I might be missing?

Comment: Blender uses appdata roaming folder for user preferences by default, so any user should be able to customize its own independent settings without interfering with others. Only situation I could see this failing is if there is a `config` folder inside the installation folder, or if it is being launched with any overriding command-line parameters. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63648/what-is-the-proper-way-to-update-a-portable-blender-installation-while-keeping-u/63666