# I want the same blender start up for different profiles. We have 4 different people logging into a central computer( separate windows login)

Tags: startup-file, asset, library

We have one computer designated to use blender. We can all remote log into the computer using different windows log in. Because we have different log ins we all have different profiles or start up files.  We want one consistent start up file that we can all use. Specifically, we want all want access to the the same asset library without having to individual set up each link.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Look into setting up a "portable" installation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63648/what-is-the-proper-way-to-update-a-portable-blender-installation-while-keeping-u. Though it might potentially share other things like settings or addons

Comment: `We have one computer designated to use blender.`  This feels very weird.  Especially the remote login - Windows only allows a single user for RDP sessions (most Desktop licensing, anyways).  Note that if these are domain-managed machines, the "proper" thing to do is probably to get the blender preferences file added to the Windows user profile (although you'd probably want local instances of blender).

Answer (score 0):

I think the quick n dirty method would be to maintain a repo where you can save the desired startup file, and make a batch file that copies the file from the repo to %appdata%'s blender directory.

Task Scheduler can be used to run the batch file on login, so any time you update the file it'll be loaded when each user logs in.

Not exactly turnkey, but it's free and fairly easy, and doesn't require any special environment (barely any permissions, even).