# Multiple Recent File problem

Tags: interface

I wonder if you can help me. I tend to have more than one portable version of blender on my computer and like to use the 'Recent Files' to keep track of what I am working on (I know it's bad practice). The problem I have is when I open a new portable version of Blender, and save work, my older versions of Blender adopt the 'Recent Files' of the new version. This means if I go back to something on an old version my Recent Files list has been overwritten. Is there any way of preserving the Recent Files list in each Blender version? Does installing Blender rather than using the portable version solve my issue?
Many thanks.

Comment: Each installed version of Blender keeps its own recent files list.

Comment: You should not open files saved with newer versions with older versions. That will often corrupt data and lead into problems for sure. It's a really bad idea to work this way. Even newer versions break some features when you open files saved with older versions. Whatever you are doing this way, I would recommend maybe asking a separate question about that to find a workaround or proper way to do that.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Yes. I should have added that to my comment. Although I actually have four versions installed at the moment, I'm always very careful about saving blend files in a folder marked for the specific version used to create them..

Comment: I have learned this the hard way. :D Switching versions in the middle of a project is not always a good idea even when you want to update to a newer better version because of features or rendering speed increase, but continuously working with different versions on purpose is definitely a terrible one.

Comment: If they are overwriting recent files lists then they aren't actual portable versions properly setup. See how to make a true portable version https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63648/what-is-the-proper-way-to-update-a-portable-blender-installation-while-keeping-u