How to have an add-on/extension folder dedicated to a given instance of Blender with Blender 4.2?
I've been developing an add-on for several years now and I have to maintain it for several versions of Blender (3.6, 4.1 and now 4.2).
I then have various versions of Blender unzipped in separated folders, and I launch the one I need from Visual Studio Code when I have to check the changes I did on the add-on. Thanks to a very useful trick, each version is completely autonomous from the others regarding the add-ons it uses, they all have their own local add-on folder.
The trick consists in manually creating a folder named "config" in the Blender directory that is named from the version. For example, in the folder where I unzipped Blender 4.1, I went to the sub-folder named 4.1 and added an empty folder "config".
Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work anymore with Blender 4.2. With the introduction of the "extensions", these extensions as well as legacy add-ons are now all gathered in a common user folder located in %AppData%\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.2\scripts\addons (on Windows).
Not being able to have a local extension/add-on folder makes the development of add-ons very (VERY!!) complicated 
So my question is this: Is there a way to have this local folder back?
Thanks a lot for any help.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63666/19307

Thanks for the link ❤❤❤ That indeed helped to answer my question.
So the solution is: for Blender 4.2 and upper versions, the new trick consists in adding a folder named "portable" at the same level as the blender.exe. Works perfectly!!! Solved also the launch issue I had to run 4.2 with VSC !!!
